# How do I get absolute URL's to work locally?

Tags: php, url, absolute

Everything works how I want on my live website, but because I'm using absolute URL's in my `header.php` and `footer.php` they don't work when I'm working locally (XAMPP) - I can't figure out how to get it working on both.

**Header.php**

```
<div id="top"><center><img src="http://cosworth-europe.com/images/header.png" style="max-width:100%;"></center></div>
<header id="header" class="site-header" role="banner">
<div id="header-inner" class="container sixteen columns over">
<hgroup class="one-third column alpha">

</hgroup>
    <nav id="main-nav" class="two thirds column omega">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/about-us.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/news.php">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/dealers.php">Dealers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/products.php">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/shop">Buy Online</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/contactus.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
</header>
```

**Code to grab `header.php`**

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/header.php"); ?>
```

**FTP Folder Structure**
[image: **FTP Folder Structure**]

Comment: The issue is that you use absolute URLs. You should not, there is no reason for that. If you cannot change that (whyever), then you have to look for a workaround, but that should always be second choice: you could modify your local name resolution to resolve the host name in those URLs to your local IP address. Maybe you additionally have to define a matching host in your local http server.

Comment: Use a leading `/` instead.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the answers, Relative URL's work fine, but only if the web pages are in the same directory as my header.php. If I have another directory inside, with web pages in, they are then looking for /index.php, when they need to be looking for ../index.php. What can I do?

Comment: @s.poole See my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relative urls, its recomended for portability.

```
</hgroup>
    <nav id="main-nav" class="two thirds column omega">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/news.php">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/dealers.php">Dealers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/products.php">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/shop">Buy Online</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/contactus.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Relative URLs as above work fine, but they don't work on webpages in other directories to my header.php - make sense?

Comment: add a trailing / to the urls, that will always point to the root directory

Comment: I've never been so frustrated over something so simple, I got it working! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always use relative URLs, at least to the domain.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

If you really wanna use absolute URLs, set a variable as `$homeroot` and use it this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $homeroot; ?>/css/style.css" />
```

And you can declare it this way:

```
$homeroot = "http://my.example.com";
```

If you still want that to be more better, you can use this way:

```
$homeroot = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things.

First -

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a> // The relative urls
```

Second -

Define a variable with the host name -

```
$host = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'www.cosworth-europe.co.uk') ? 'http://www.cosworth-europe.co.uk' : 'http://localhost';
```

And

```
<a href="<?php echo $host;?>/index.php">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use absolute URLs, if you sometimes have to change something you will have a big mess with it.

You should use either a function or relative URLs.

**Function example:**

```
function getURL() {
    //get THIS ($develop) value from a config file
    $develop = true;

    return ( $develop ) ? "localhost" : "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
}
```

i.e.

```
<a href="<?php echo getURL(); ?>/index.php">Home</a>
```

**QUICKHELP:**
Just edit your hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   www.cosworth-europe.co.uk
```

**Relative URLs (relative from doc root in this example)**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/news.php">News</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Relative URL's as above work fine, but only if the web pages are in the same directory as my header.php. If I have another directory inside, with web pages in, they are then looking for /index.php, when they need to be looking for ../index.php. What can I do?

Comment: with a `/` you are always refeering to your domain like `example.org/` or `localhost/` so if header.php is in another folder that is not a problem, but you have to adjust the link. i.e. you want to call `localhost/somefolder/index,php` your href has to be `/somefolder/index.php`but this wont work for both cases if your root folder at the domains is at `www.cosworth-europe.co.uk/` and locally it's on `localhost/cosworth/`

Comment: But how can I adjust the links? this will just stop my header appearing on web pages it already works on! So confusing :@

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work **without editing your source file**:

Actually, you shouldn't have done with absolute URL's, but still you can make it to work locally, you need small changes in `hosts` file. I don't know which OS you are currently in, so you can edit hosts like this:

**Ubuntu:**

In your terminal, type

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

You will be required to enter your password.
In the file opened add this line to the end:

```
127.0.0.1   www.cosworth-europe.co.uk
```

**Windows:**

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Open this in notepad with administrative privilege and add the above lines. Now local works in the similar way to your live website.

[But make sure to remove these lines, if you want to access live website (www.cosworth-europe.co.uk)]

See this for [pictorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) representation. In this method you need not change your files for now. But it is strongly recommended to use relative URLs for excellent portability!

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work? I edited the file and replaced `127.0.0.1   localhost` with `127.0.0.1   www.cosworth-europe.co.uk`, ran site locally in XAMPP and still no change, did I do it correct?

Comment: So you should enter `www.cosworth-europe.co.uk` in the URL not localhost. by the way why are you replacing localhost, just add one more line to it

Comment: Sorry I'm sure your answer works fine but this is probably all too advanced for me. I think I'll just have to leave it :-(

Comment: Then you should change your code, that's the only way! `<a href="index.php">Home</a>`

Comment: I completely agree, but I can't get relative URL's to work if my web pages are in different directories :@

Comment: if your page is in different directory, you should include that too.. like `my/directory/products.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96979/discussion-between-s-poole-and-myway).